# SQLalchemy and method inside column property

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have this `column_property` which checks how many credits a user is allowed:

```
select(
    [func.ifnull( func.sum( orders_table.c.quantity ), 0 )],
    orders_table.c.user_id == users_table.c.id
).where( and_(
    orders_table.c.date_added < now_unix(),
    orders_table.c.date_expires > now_unix(),
    orders_table.c.status == STATUS_COMPLETED
) ).label( 'userAllowedCredits' ),
deferred = True
```

The `now_unix()` method returns the current unix timestamp but the problem is that this method is loaded only once and every time I call this `userAllowedCredits` property the query searches based on the same initial value that was saved when my app was started. I need this `now_unix()` method to return the actual current timestamp at every call.

Do I make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably store this expression at startup, so now_unix() is only executed at that time. From the SqlAlchemys point of view, it's just a value. How to solve this, depends a bit on your use case. You could use [now()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now), which would use the database build in `now()` function. If you have to use your own `now_unix()`, you can still pass it as a parameter.

Comment: used `func.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` since *Any name can be given to func. If the function name is unknown to SQLAlchemy, it will be rendered exactly as is. For common SQL functions which SQLAlchemy is aware of, the name may be interpreted as a generic function which will be compiled appropriately to the target database*